# How not suspend all threads in Visual Studio 2022 when C++ native breakpoint is reached?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I want to set a breakpoint and have the threads that reach it suspend, but I want those threads that have not reached a breakpoint to continue executing as though nothing has happened. Unavoidable consequences of doing this are acceptable to me. In my code, I will have properly synchronized between threads, copied data, and so on. If I do see an unexpected consequence then I've found a bug or learned something interesting about my code.

I found this Stack Overflow article regarding Visual Studio 2008.

[VS2008 Suspending all threads upon hitting breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858200/vs2008-suspending-all-threads-upon-hitting-breakpoint)

The article unofficially says Visual Studio 2008 cannot do what I'm asking for in this question. Version 2008 is many versions before today's 2022 yet I still have not found that for which I'm looking.

Before I give up my search, I'm asking this community, Is there a way in Visual Studio C++ native projects to suspend only threads that have reached breakpoints and have all others continue?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/get-started-debugging-multithreaded-apps?view=vs-2022#bkmk_follow_a_thread

Comment: Breakpoint conditions do not accomplish what I need. A condition on a breakpoint adds a boolean predicate on an ordinary breakpoint. When a thread reaches a breakpoint with a predicate the predicate must be true otherwise the breakpoint is not triggered. I'm not trying to adjust when a breakpoint is triggered. I'm trying to adjust what happens when a breakpoint is triggered. I want the thread that triggered the breakpoint to stop normally. Also normally all other threads stop as well. Instead, I want all other threads to continue as though nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

In the thread panel, you can resume the execution of the other threads.
If you want that the other threads does not stop, I don't know a way of doing it sadly.

Comment: Thank you for the information.